# Why my local variable in a function affect global variable without using 'global'?

Tags: python, function, global-variables, local-variables

I am still learning about python. I am stuck with this local variable behavior. I am trying to make a simple coffee machine. this is the part of code.

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.5,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.5,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.0,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}

def calculate(current, ingredients):
    remaining = current
    print(remaining)
    print(ingredients)
    for i in ingredients :
        remaining[i] = remaining[i] - ingredients[i]
        if remaining[i] < 0 :
            print(f"sorry, there is not enough {i}")
            print(remaining)
            return resources
    return remaining

user_input = input("What would you like? (espresso/latte/cappuccino): ").lower()
coffee = MENU[user_input]
ingredients = coffee["ingredients"]
cost = coffee["cost"]
# check if coffee can be made.
remaining = calculate(resources, ingredients)
print(resources)
print(remaining)
```

When I run it, I expect that the global variable of resources won't change. If I choose latte, the output should be like this:

```
{'water': 300, 'milk': 200, 'coffee': 100}
{'water': 50, 'milk': 100, 'coffee': 76}
```

However, the printed resources change its value. I noticed using thonny debugger that when the calculation occurs, both local and global change their value. I didn't use global command. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources` is a mutable object. When it is passed to `calculate`, `current` becomes another name for that object.

`remaining = current` assigns another name to the object, and `remaining[i] = remaining[i] - ingredients[i]` mutates that object.

To fix, use:

```
remaining = current.copy()
```

This will make a new object that modifying won’t affect the original.

Note that if the original object itself contains mutable objects, then `copy.deepcopy()` may be needed, but not in this case.

Comment: is that mean that any variable assigned to function(variable) can be modified? or is it apply only to dictionary?

Comment: Any *mutable* value. `remaining` is a *local variable* that refers to the same object as the global variable `current`. You never modify the variable after its initialization; `remaining[i] = ...` is syntax for invoking a mutating method call `remaining.__setitem__(i, ...)`.

Comment: Only if you mutate mutable objects (e.g. list, dict, set).  Immutable objects (e.g. int, float, str, bytes) can’t be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the value of `resources` as it's a mutable object.

Here's the initial declared value:

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
}
```

You then make a function call to calculate which (i've replaced current with RESOURCES to help visualize) you then just say `remaining = RESOURCES` by saying `remaining = current`. The argument could be named anything, what you pass in is the value. In this case that is a mutable (changeable) object.

```
remaining = calculate(resources, ingredients)

def calculate(RESOURCES, ingredients):
    remaining = RESOURCES
```

Once you understand that, it's easy to see why the following changes the value of `resources`, you assigned remaining to be the mutable dictionary you passed in, so by changing it's  values you change the value of the object it represents.

```
for i in ingredients :
    remaining[i] = remaining[i] - ingredients[i]
```

Here's another way to think about it if that doesn't click:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x = ['a', 'b']
```

if I `print(y)`, the value will be `[1, 2, 3]`, however if I did `x[0] = 2` my output for `print(y)` would then become `[2, 2, 3]` as I've changed the **value** of my mutable object `x`.

It sounds like you want to pass in a copy of resources, so try using `dict2 = dict(dict1)`. This is also a great example of how a class and the factory design pattern may be of use to you.

Comment: So, when the rule of local and global variables applies? I tried your code about x and y using the same calculate function by adding x and y. I printout x and x_new, the result is different like this: x = [1, 2, 3] ; x_new = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']. Why the global x did not change like my code above?

Comment: The reason it changed above is because you are directly accessing that object `x[0]`. When you do that, you're directly assigning a new value to that index. When you do something like `x_new = x + y`, you aren't changing the original x var.